Using python3.11 on an AWS login node via Slurm
I can install python3.11 on the AWS cluster ok, see this post.
However, running a python script submitted via Slurm ends up using python3.9.
I created a virtual environment and ensured it uses python3.11,
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-96-215 ~]$ source /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-96-215 ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.1

and activated this via the job script:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=random_graph_simulation
#SBATCH --output=output4.log
#SBATCH --error=error4.log
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN,END,FAIL
# Load any required modules or set up your Python environment here
#SBATCH --export=ALL

source /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/activate

python3 --version
echo "PATH: $PATH"
which python3

# Run your Python script
python3 script.py

but it's still running python3.9,

Python 3.9.20 PATH:
/home/ec2-user/myenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin/:/opt/amazon/efa/bin/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/us$
/opt/parallelcluster/pyenv/versions/3.9.20/envs/awsbatch_virtualenv/bin/python3

and my code needs python3.11. What is going on? How can I get the login node (that Slurm assigns the job to) to use the correct version of python?
